# highstock - control when tooltip appears

Tags: highcharts

By default, the tooltip appears as soon as the cursor enters the chart. I would like to control when it first appears in one of two ways:

1. Wait for user to hover over (around) a data point on the chart. 
   This way the user can look at the entire chart without the
   distraction of the tooltip.
2. mousedown - is there a way to disable the default mousedown function
   and use it for displaying the tooltip instead? And because the
   tooltip and crosshair seem to be joined, perhaps the same mousedown
   event could fire the crosshair to appear?

number 2 would be best; any suggestions/solutions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Number 2 is possible to achieve by:

1. disable default Highcharts tooltip
2. create `point.click` event handler
3. in above handler, create your own tooltip (it's simple div with some CSS)
4. make proper position for tooltip (accessed via `this.point.plotX` and `this.point.plotY`

Comment: @Patrick this question has been open for a long time. You should accept Pawel's answer (just click the "check mark" on the left side) if it fixed your problem, so that others know this is the right answer.